# Dealing with Sequence of dependent Functions

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture

I have several functions that rely on remote resource to return a result.
This remote resource has a lot of errors or unexpected response that I can not change.
There is a sequence of functions that each depends on the results of the function before.
The logic of each function is different.

For example:

```
bool remoteFunction(string resource, string parameter = "")
{
// for example request
//for simplicity this is considered a request, but each function has different logic
return request.Url("example.com" + resource, parameter);
}

var firstResult = remoteFunction("a");                  //1st step
var secondResult = remoteFunction("b", firstResult);    //2nd step
var thirdResult = remoteFunction("c", secondResult);    //3rd step
var fourthResult = remoteFunction("d", thirdResult);    //4rth steo
```

What I want to do is:

- Keep retrying to do the function until it return the result we want.
  This can be done inside or outside the function.
- I want to be able to
  jump back from one function to a previous one and continue through
  the flow. i.e: jump from 4th step to 2nd step and continue from
  there.

What is the best design to do this ?

Thanks for the help

---

Clarification:
To be more clear, I only want to go back in the sequence only if a function throws an exception. i.e:
if 4rd function throws an exception, i have to go back to 1st and continue from there.

Comment: There never is a best design. What ideas have you come up so far?

Comment: To do what you want you need to run each function asynchronously.  Then you need to be able to select one function to run.  The selection could be done by putting the code into a switch block with each function a different case.

Comment: @jdweng those functions need to be ran in sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't clear they need to be run in sequence.  Here is the code

```
            var firstResult;
            var secondResult;
            var thirdResult;
            var fourthResult;
            int start = 3;
            for (int i = start; i < 4; i++)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0 :
                        firstResult = remoteFunction("a"); 
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        secondResult = remoteFunction("b", firstResult);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        thirdResult = remoteFunction("c", secondResult);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        fourthResult = remoteFunction("d", thirdResult);
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think this is incomplete;  The OP mentioned that each function is dependent upon the result of the previous function in the sequence, but this answer doesn't seem to address that part of the question.

Comment: From description is sounds like the op doesn't need to repeat methods that passed.  So he want to continue from function that failed.

Comment: Read my comment again; the question is asking about calling functions in sequence by passing the **result** of the previous function as an argument to the next function.